# Inception v3 guide on tensorflow broken for C++ and python

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm following the guide here on running the pretrained inception v3 https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

However, when I try the python version, I get:

```
python classify_image.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_image.py", line 227, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'
```

Ok.. Fine nevermind let me try the C++ Version.

Downloaded the model, run the bazel command:

```
➜  tensorflow git:(master) ✗ bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
.......
ERROR: /storage/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:636:21: syntax error at '=': expected expression.
ERROR: /storage/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:711:1: nested functions are not allowed. Move the function to top-level.
ERROR: /storage/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:739:1: nested functions are not allowed. Move the function to top-level.
ERROR: /storage/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:773:1: nested functions are not allowed. Move the function to top-level.
ERROR: /storage/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:776:1: nested functions are not allowed. Move the function to top-level.
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '': Extension 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' has errors.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.600s
```

...Okay then. Neither seems to work. Or perhaps I'm doing this wrong. Anyone has any guidance? :)

Using tensorflow 0.11 on Ubuntu 16, Anaconda distribution python 3.5

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone's interested, the python one was easy to solve by just removing the argv command. Leaving it here as a note that the document should be changed to reflect this.

Comment: Could you [file a bug on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new) to track this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone:

Solving the C++ problem: Update Bazel to the correct version (you likely installed tensorflow ages ago and git pulled the latest which requires a new bazel version)

Solving the python problem: Remove the argv command.