# tensorflow retrain.py app.run() got unexpected keyword argument 'argv'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run the Tensorflow for Poets sample.  I pass the following:

`python examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --bottlenext_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks --how_many_training_steps 500 --model_dir=tf_files/inception --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --image_dir tf_files/flower_photos`

I get the error

`File "examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1013, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'`

When I check the source of app.py it shows argv as an argument.  According to t.**version** I am running 0.11.0rc0

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more details on how the build is done?  I see [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357548/inception-v3-guide-on-tensorflow-broken-for-c-and-python) recommended as a bug report to the TF GitHub site.  [This posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467893/running-mnist-softmax-py-on-tensorflow-installed-with-docker) hit the problem with Docker.

Comment: Thanks.  I installed into a virtualenv with conda.  I just tried reinstalling using the command "conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow".  It installed version 0.11.0rc2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier. Downloading the examples from a different branch fixed it.

```
git clone -b r0.11 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Comment: Did you just use the new retrain.py file, or did you build it all from sources?

Comment: Switching to the version you posted fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your sample's version. I met the same problem and finally solved it. I found my tf version is 0.11, but I downloaded the master one,
then I compare the code asyntax difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can also specifically checkout just the working `fully_connected_feed.py` file from the r0.11 branch by using the git command:

`git checkout 5b18edb fully_connected_feed.py`

**NOTE: You need to be in the mnist/ directory to use this command**