# codelab tutorial tensorflow errorxxx

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, cmd, pip

**once I run the following code on windows 10 tensor flow version 1.7.1**

```
python -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

**I get the following error**

```
line 1326, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

Can somebody help me please:(

Comment: i suggest to update your tensorflow version(2.x), and read this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/flags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258003/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-app)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btensorflow%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27tensorflow%27+has+no+attribute+%27app%27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [tensorflow retrain.py app.run() got unexpected keyword argument 'argv'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513466/tensorflow-retrain-py-app-run-got-unexpected-keyword-argument-argv)

I think you need to update the version of your tensorflow.